# 2D grid with selectable items in c# Wforms?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gridview

How can be done a 2D of 10x10 selectable elements each element with text in a windows form? 
Is there an easy way of doing this?

I need to select some elements in an orderable way (indexed) in the grid in order to send new positions to my robot. I mean: 1st: go to first selected element of the grid (labeled as 1 when selected)
                               2nd: go to the second selected element of the grid (labeled as 2 when selected)               ... and so on...

The grid would look like this: [image: 2d grid]
<sub>(source: [xmswiki.com](http://www.xmswiki.com/xms/images/d/d0/GridType1.gif))</sub>

**I am trying to avoid putting 100 checkboxes close to each other**...

Comment: May I suggest WPF instead? it's really much more scalable, customizable, and simply beautiful. You can actually achieve that in WPF with a ListBox.

Comment: I guess that it's not the right moment to change from Wforms to WPF... It would be a great change I guess. This is a part of a PC program that enables user interface with our robot. This robot is for my grade project in Electronic Engineering... We are thinking of adding this feature in the program if this doesn't take us more than 1 week... We should be delivering the final documentation in a couple of months...

Comment: @leouru I already have a running version of it... I was about to start doing the animations part, if you want I can post the code.

Comment: That would be great @HighCore! Thanks!

Comment: How does the robot actually move? does it just go in a straight line from point A to point B? what about acceleration / deceleration?

Comment: Yes, it moves from A to B in a straight line. It uses a PID controller for the motors. Also, the robot is like a cylinder with 2 wheels in opposite sides and 2 Pololu Ball Casters...

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer because the OP asked for it:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.GridRobot"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GridRobot" Height="500" Width="600">
<DockPanel>

    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Size:" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Size}" IsReadOnly="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="2" Width="50"/>
        <Slider Maximum="20" Minimum="2" Value="{Binding Size}"/>
    </DockPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" Margin="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Route:" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Route}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:D2},{1:D2}">
                                <Binding Path="Row"/>
                                <Binding Path="Column"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Size}" Columns="{Binding Size}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.GoToCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border Background="#05FFFFFF">
                                        <Viewbox>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PathIndex}" 
                                            TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Viewbox>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Canvas>
            <!-- I was about to add the Robot Peg here and animate it -->
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class GridRobot : Window
{
    public GridRobot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new GridRobotViewModel();
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class GridRobotViewModel: PropertyChangedBase
{
    private int _size;
    public int Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set
        {
            _size = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Size");
            CreateItems();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GridItem> _squares;
    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> Squares
    {
        get { return _squares ?? (_squares = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>()); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GridItem> _route;
    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> Route
    {
        get { return _route ?? (_route = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>()); }
    }

    private void CreateItems()
    {
        Squares.Clear();
        Route.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
            {
                Squares.Add(new GridItem() {Row = i, Column = j});
            }
        }
    }

    private Command<GridItem> _goToCommand;
    public Command<GridItem> GoToCommand
    {
        get { return _goToCommand ?? (_goToCommand = new Command<GridItem>(Goto){IsEnabled = true}); }
    }

    private void Goto(GridItem item)
    {
        if (item.PathIndex == null)
        {
            item.PathIndex = Squares.Max(x => x.PathIndex ?? 0) + 1;

            Route.Add(item);    
        }
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class GridItem: PropertyChangedBase
{
    public int Row { get; set; }

    public int Column { get; set; }

    private int? _pathIndex;
    public int? PathIndex
    {
        get { return _pathIndex; }
        set
        {
            _pathIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PathIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

Support Classes for MVVM:

```
public class PropertyChangedBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }));
    }
}

public class Command<T>: ICommand
{
    public Action<T> Action { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Action != null && parameter is T)
            Action((T)parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsEnabled;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Command(Action<T> action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.
- You said 10 x 10, but I went a step further and added a Slider to make the grid size customizable.
- Clicking on any cell will make it be queued as part of the Route.
- Fully Resolution Independent.
- I was about to start putting some really nice stuff on it (animations, robot movement represented by an ellipse, Lines for the Path, etc).
- Forget winforms, it's useless.

Comment: It's really beautiful. It exactly what i was thinking... With the route info i can set functions in the robot to follow it... How much would it take me as a EE student to learn WPF? If I have known WPF in the past i'd have chosen it... Also, ObservableCollection, INotifyPropertyChanged, PropertyChangedEventHandler and PropertyChangedEventArgs aren't found... What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you have resharper? Ctrl+Enter autocompletes the references, you need `using System.ComponentModel`, `using System.Collections.Generic`. Otherwise `Ctrl+.` in Visual Studio

Comment: No, i don´t... Excellent! I was also missing using System.Collections.ObjectModel;... Isn't it possible to be done for windows form? please understand that i have to finish my grade project... I guess it would be crazy to change the whole program right now... Maybe if not that crazy... For future projects i will use WPF for sure!

Comment: @leo2_uru I have no idea. I never used winforms. I consider it a dinosaur only comparable with java stuff. The DataBinding capabilities that WPF brings allows me to write really clean code. That doesn't exist in winforms.

Comment: @leo2_uru anyways... you could integrate my WPF stuff inside an existing winforms application using the `ElementHost` if you wanted... I mean, you don't really have to change all the existing stuff.