# How to create grid in Win Store App using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, store

I have created this grid :

```
Grid grid = new Grid // new Grid
{
    Width = 1500,
    Height = 1500,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Coral)
};

var columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(200) }; // column
var columnDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(200) };
var columnDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(200) };
var columnDefinition3 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(200) };

grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition); // add column to grid
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition1);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition2);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition3);

var rowDefinition = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(300) }; // row
var rowDefinition1 = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(300) };
var rowDefinition2 = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(300) };
var rowDefinition3 = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(300) };

grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition); // add row to grid
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition1);
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition2);
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition3);

var textBlock1 = new TextBlock // new textBlock
{
    Text = "TextBox 1 ",
    FontSize = 20,
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
    Width = 100
};

Grid.SetColumn(textBlock1, 0); 
Grid.SetRow(textBlock1, 0); 

var rec = new Rectangle(); // new Rectangle
{
    Width = 70;
    Height = 70;

    rec.Fill = linearGradientBrush;
}

Grid.SetColumn(rec, 1);
Grid.SetRow(rec, 0);
grid.Children.Add(textBlock1); 
grid.Children.Add(rec); 
MainGrid.Children.Add(grid); // Add grid to main grid
```

But all I can see is small rectangle of coral color (which is color of my grid) in the middle of the screen. I know it's easier to create grid using XAML, I just want to know how to do it in C#. Thanks for help

Comment: creating UI elements in procedural code in XAML-based technologies is discouraged, cumbersome, probably a bad idea, and just plain wrong. There is no logical reason to do this.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks. Do you have some useful link where I could read about this?

Comment: @HighCore: what if you don't know what UI elements are needed until runtime, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26856909/886887)?

Comment: @HarryJohnston `I want there to be a certain number of...` - That's an `ItemsControl`. If you come up with a real scenario of what you need I can tell you how to do it properly. I have not, to this day, with 4+ years of WPF development under my belt and dozens of UIs and custom controls and whatnot, stumbled upon a SINGLE scenario where I was forced to create UI elements in procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
rec.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
rec.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
```

Similarly for your textblock..

Comment: Gives me exactly same result

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem I see in your code is that you add the `Grid` children *after* you try to set the attached property. I believe the element needs to already be a child of the `Grid` object before you set the attached property. Otherwise, how would the static method know which `Grid` object's attached property should be set?

This code, an event handler subscribed to the `Grid`'s `Loaded` event, works fine for me:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int rows = 2, columns = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        RowDefinition definition = new RowDefinition();

        definition.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(definition);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        ColumnDefinition definition = new ColumnDefinition();

        definition.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(definition);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            TextBlock text = new TextBlock();

            text.Text = string.Format("column: {0}, row: {1}", j, i);
            text.FontSize = 36;
            text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            text.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            text.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
            grid.Children.Add(text);

            Grid.SetRow(text, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(text, j);
        }
}
```

Comment: -1 your answer goes against all well-known, established practices and patterns in XAML based technologies. Also, all your horrible code can be replaced by a couple of lines of proper XAML.

Comment: @ HighCore well it might be against best practices but I just wanted to know how to do it :).

Comment: @HighCore: thanks for the editorial. You seem to be one of those dogmatic folks who can't stand the idea of procedural leaking into their declarative. Still, I notice you haven't bothered to actually _post_ an answer. So your claim that it's possible to address the OP's question in a strictly declarative way remains unsubstantiated. If you want to share knowledge that's great, but if you're just going to insult other people, I'm not sure why you are here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho LOL you have to be kidding. I can give you countless examples of answers I've posted in the past explaining how to do this **properly** in WPF. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344022/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-textbox-that-has-been-pressed) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21004225/643085) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16227842/643085) I can find more if you want. I didn't post here because it would be *yet another* "delete all your code and start all over" type of answer, which I sincerely don't have time for right now.