# Displaying a window in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a WPF UI for an little toy program I have written in C#. The program just finds the shortest path between two points. The display creates a grid of squares that display the type of cell it is (empty space, asteroid, gravity well, gravity influenced, start, finish, and path).

What is the best way for me to run the UI that I have created? I just made the `Window` variable in my UI a public variable and created an `Application` in my `Program.cs` class and called `Run` on the `Window`. I have tried `Run`-ing two different windows at once, and only one would display - how do I get both to display?

Also, is there a way to make it so that my grid updates whenever the contents of the array that describe each cell change? e.g. if a cell changed from an asteroid to empty space, which has a different color, is there a way to make my UI know that it changed and update accordingly?

Here is the source code for the UI:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    public class SpaceProbeView
    {
        public Window window = new Window();
        public Window optionWindow = new Window();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        private int cellSize = 25;
        SpaceProbeModel model;
        int rowAndColumnSize;
        SolidColorBrush emptySpaceBrush = Brushes.DarkBlue;
        SolidColorBrush asteroidBrush = Brushes.DarkGreen;
        SolidColorBrush gravityWellBrush = Brushes.Magenta;
        SolidColorBrush gravityInfluencedBrush = Brushes.DarkMagenta;
        SolidColorBrush pathBrush = Brushes.DarkTurquoise;
        SolidColorBrush startBrush = Brushes.Black;
        SolidColorBrush finishBrush = Brushes.DarkOrange;
        Brush outlineBrush = Brushes.Black;

        public SpaceProbeView(int size)
        {
            rowAndColumnSize = size;
            window.Title = "Space Probe";
            canvas.Width = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            canvas.Height = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            window.Width = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            window.Height = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            window.Content = canvas;
            window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

            //window.Show();
            optionWindow.Width = 100;
            optionWindow.Height = 200;
            //optionWindow.Show();
        }

        public void SetModel(SpaceProbeModel aModel)
        {
            model = aModel;
            for (int row = 0; row < rowAndColumnSize; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < rowAndColumnSize; column++)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.Width = cellSize;
                    rect.Height = cellSize;
                    rect.Stroke = outlineBrush;

                    switch (model.cellType[row, column])
                    {
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.start:
                            rect.Fill = startBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.finish:
                            rect.Fill = finishBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.asteroid:
                            rect.Fill = asteroidBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.gravityInfluenced:
                            rect.Fill = gravityInfluencedBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.gravityWell:
                            rect.Fill = gravityWellBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.empty:
                            rect.Fill = emptySpaceBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.path:
                            rect.Fill = pathBrush;
                            break;
                    }
                    Canvas.SetTop(rect, row * cellSize);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, column * cellSize);
                    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my `Program.cs` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpaceProbeView view = new SpaceProbeView(30);
            SpaceProbeModel model = new SpaceProbeModel(30, 20, 1);
            model.Start = new SpaceProbeModel.CellPair(5, 5);
            model.FindShortestPath(20, 25);
            view.SetModel(model);
            Application app = new Application();
            app.Run(view.window);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again, delete all that and use proper XAML.

Comment: @HighCore lol I was wondering if you were going to show up again. From what I can tell XAML is just for overall UI layout and code behind for design logic, which seems to be what I am doing - logic, right? What am I missing?

Comment: What you're doing is not "design logic", what you're doing is grabbing data from a data model and manually putting it into the UI instead of using DataBinding. What you need here is an `ItemsControl` with a `UniformGrid`, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16227842/643085).

Comment: You should probably also read through the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.